# Remove navigation bar (invisible) padding

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm triying to create a horizontal nav bar in my website. The problem is when I hover over one of the options. It gets highlighted but not as I want. This is the result:

[image]

As you can see there's some space which should be highlighted as well but it's not.

My Html and CSS:

```css
.section ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5fb763;
}
.section ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}
.section ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
.section ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 100%;
}
.section ul li a.active {
  background-color: rgba(198, 186, 186, 0.73);
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="#section1">El local</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tutorials"><a href="#section2">Como Llegar</a>
    </li>
    <li class="about"><a class="active">Historia</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <hr />
  <hr />
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `line-height` in `li`

`line-height: 21px;`

```css
    .section ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5fb763;
}
.section ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 21px;
}
.section ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
.section ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 100%;
}
.section ul li a.active {
  background-color: rgba(198, 186, 186, 0.73);
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="#section1">El local</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tutorials"><a href="#section2">Como Llegar</a>
    </li>
    <li class="about"><a class="active">Historia</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support IE8. I would look at maybe using the `nav` tag instead for your needs. Consider the following snippet;

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
nav a.active {
  background-color: rgba(198, 186, 186, 0.73);
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <a href="#section1">El local</a>
    
    <a href="#section2">Como Llegar</a>

    <a class="active">Historia</a>
  </nav>
</body>
```

With your current solution you'll need to float the `li` elements in order to get the correct behaviour with specified widths I believe. You could also consider a flexbox solution.

There are some simple guidelines to creating CSS navigation bars [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp).

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: Thanks mate! Good answer but it's easier for me to add the line-height :)

Comment: No worries. Ah yes, that's fair enough :) Just be careful not to define too many properties that will maybe make your layout components more complicated to maintain down the line if changes need to be made.